# Could not create Directory wordpress local host error

Tags: wordpress, apache, xampp, localhost

Folks!
I am having problem uploading "ShopKeeper" theme on WordPress which is running on my own computer. I am a newbie and learning WordPress but whenever I upload theme it says (the error in the image)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fTjP.png)

I am using Xampp

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet, so this will be as an answer.

From what I see, it looks like you are trying to unpack the wrong zip file.

Please open the Archive you downloaded, you should then see a folder named `Theme Files`, ***or something similar***, and you will find inside a .zip file.

Try to install the archive located here, and it should work.

Also, if it's not working yet, it might be due to permissions, which I don't believe. You should check your `error logs`. You will find them under the folder Applications of `Xampp`.